# IDE for Developing windows phone 8 applications in Ubuntu

Tags: application-development, windows-phone

I used to work with Ubuntu, and I don't want to switch back to Windows platform. I am participating in a code contest. In that contest, I need to create windows phone 8 apps.

I need an IDE in Ubuntu for the same, with windows phone 8 emulator.

Is it possible ?

Comment: no.  not without heavy wine or vm usage.  targeting windows os without just using qt is a lost cause.

Comment: You *could* use a VM. Otherwise no, not possible.

Comment: Did you try MonoDevelop. I guess that support .net framework

Comment: @NiteshVerma Yes, and it runs desktop Windows projects - but not WindowsPhone, which need signing and registering to set up development device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel XDK *NEW* is your answer.Its free too.